# Facebook login in react app

Tags: reactjs, facebook-login

I have been trying to create a login in my react app using Facebook developer login. I have been following these steps (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web#checklogin). 
My project can be found here - [Github Repo](https://github.com/sugandhgoyal/Facebook-Login-React-App)

Here I have created a login page that shows the login button and a Homepage that should be shown after logging in. Now how should I show the Home page after logging in? The below image shows the redirect url I have put in the App Dashboard.
[image: Do I have to put this homepage url in this?]
Am I correct to understand that this is for re-directing the page after logging in?
I have placed the code in index.html file and LoginPage>index.js file.
Please help me I am not able to understand this further.

Comment: you really do not need redirection, just use the js sdk (FB.login, FB.getLoginStatus). also, i would not put the js sdk init code into the html...you could put it in a redux action, with a reducer that stores user info and a flag if the js sdk is loaded.

Comment: How will it redirect then? My login and logout are working fine after using  FB.getLoginStatus, but it is staying on the same page. And what do I have to write in this redirect URL in my App Dashboard?

Comment: you just redirect on your own, with react-router, for example. forget about the redirect url in the app dashboard, you can keep it empty